# Using FMDB to Rollback Transactions in Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, transactions, fmdb

So I am trying to use FMDB in Swift. I have everything hooked up fine as far as bridging headers and such, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use transactions in the `FMDatabaseQueue` class. Specifically I do not understand the syntax to rollback a transaction. I have tried the code below but it yields a compile time error of

```
'UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>' does not have a member named 'initialize'
```

I am sure this has to do with the fact that a pointer is being passed into the closure for rollback, but as far as I am aware you cannot reassign variables passed into closures in swift, so I'm not sure how I am suppose to set the pointer to indicate a rollback is needed.

```
if let queue = FMDatabaseQueue(path: DB_PATH) {
    queue.inTransaction() {
        db, rollback in

        // This could be any statement, drop table is just an example
        success = db.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE test", withArgumentsInArray:nil)

        if !success {
            // Need to rollback here
            rollback.initialize(true)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to indicate a rollback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the closure, `rollback` is a pointer to a boolean variable
and you can set it to `true` with:

```
if !success {
    rollback.memory = true
    return
}
```

In **Swift 3** it would be

```
    rollback.pointee = true
```

Comment: This did just the trick. I'm not sure why I can't find any solid documentation on 'UnsafePointer'. I would never have guessed to directly set the memory field. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MechIntel: You are welcome. But note that Rob's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `rollback.initialize(true)` syntax is correct. I notice, though, that your code sample has a typographical error, referencing `initalize`, not `initialize` (though curiously, your error message doesn't). When I fix that typo, your code works fine for me.

Comment: The typo seems to be a copy/paste error when I was modifying the code to strip out parts that aren't needed to illustrate the problem. I still get the same compiler error using initialize. If it helps I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and attempting to build on SDK 8.1. Are you using something different?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1, too, and it works fine. Hmm. Maybe restart Xcode? Or try producing problem in new project?

Comment: Strange... are you using the current pull of Master from FMDB? Maybe it has changed recently. I am using 2.5, which I believe is the current build.

Comment: I just pulled it right before testing it. If you upload the project somewhere, I'm happy to look at it.

Comment: I'll try to get a test project put together that demonstrates the error I am seeing when I have time. Setting the memory field seems to work for me in the meantime, but I am unsure why initialize does not. Especially if it is working for you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, not only does it compile correctly, but when I actually use the syntax, it rolls back successfully, too. Very curious...

Comment: @Rob: You are right that `initialize(true)` works as well. I now wonder which is the "correct" way of doing it. The API docs for `initialize()` state that the memory must not be initialized before (but it *is* initialized when the closure is called). Therefore I *assume* that just assigning `.memory = true` is the right way here. It probably makes no difference at all for scalar types like a boolean. What do you think?

Comment: That's valid argument. I thought I remembered some Apple example using the `initialize` technique, but can't find it now. I know that I once used the `rollback[0] = true` syntax, too, but have used `initialize()` since Xcode 6.0b4 (saddled with an even more awkward construct before that). But `.memory` seems eminently logical.